# Android studio not refreshing new versions

Tags: android, android-studio

With an ASUS ZenPad10 happens that sometime I run an application but instead the old one get started. So I think to have fixed something but actually I'm testing the version that has still the bug, loosing a lot of time.

With other tablets this doesn't happen. Beside that, I need to disable ADB for starting the app in the tablet. With a Nexus 10 I have no need to do any of that.

In the /data/app directory there is also all directories (like "myapp/") instead of apks (like "myapp.apk") as in the Nexus 10.

Any idea to avoid the problems with the refresh?

I wonder if "Verify apps over USB" might be the cause, but I'm not able to disable it on the ASUS.

I think it's not necessary, but this is my main gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder/raw/master/repository'
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.5' //version required
}
```

And this is my App gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':Structure:StructureExam')
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.3.1'
    compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:0.9.6'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../../myfile.jks")
            storePassword "mypass"
            keyAlias "myalias"
            keyPassword "mypass"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for com.centervue.lib_util.errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when com.centervue.lib_util.errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean/Rebuild project and then try it again. Uninstall application from device then try.

Comment: I can make it work. But I don't to clean/uninstall manually the application every time, since it's not needed in other devices. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: Did you have instance run checked? if so then also check Restart App option too. Inastate run has problem of not running new version of apk if not restarted app.

Comment: how do I see if instance run is checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks you have instant-run ON ( which is by default ).
That feature leads to ship only changed code to app on device. that what might causing troubles you are facing...

Disable it:
[Settings/preferences] -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run : Uncheck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code..... "

Alternatively you can use  **clean and Rerun 'app'** from Run (^⌘R)

Comment: sorry for being late, I was sick without a computer :( but your is the right answer. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: FYI: [Instant Run / Hot Swap was introduced in Android 2.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run).

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio goto run -> Edit Configurations... and under app and the general tab check if you have Gradle-aware Make under "before launch". if not add it with the plus.

You should also make sure everything in your build.gradle is correct, especially under defaultConfig.

These are common fixes to the problem, however, it is strange that only one specific device is having the issue. I'll keep investigating and edit this answer if I find a solution but try these for now.

Comment: I have Gradle-aware make in my launch configuration. I've added my gradle files too. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because of the Enable ADB integration.

If I forgot it on because I'm using the debugger it either doesn't push correctly the new application or it just launches the old one.

No idea of the reason why. Disabling it will make everything work just fine. Although it's really a pain to code like this. Any idea of the reason why this doesn't work on a Nexus but it does on an ASUS?